# Pandas DataFrame mypy error: slice index must be an integer or None

Tags: python, pandas, lint, mypy

The following line

```
pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1.1, 2.2]}, index=[3.3, 4.4])[2.5:3.5]
```

raises a mypy linting error of on the `[2.5`

> Slice index must be an integer or None

This is valid syntax and correctly returns

```
     col1
3.3   1.1
```

Without `# type: ignore`, how can I resolve this linting error?

versions:

- pandas 1.3.0
- mypy 0.931

The code in question:

```
def get_dataframe(
    ts_data: GroupTs,
    ts_group_name: str,
    start_time: Optional[float] = None,
    end_time: Optional[float] = None,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame(ts_data.group[ts_group_name].ts_dict)[
        start_time:end_time
    ].interpolate(
        method="index", limit_area="inside"
    )  # type: pd.DataFrame
    return df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [by design](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2410) for now, I fear, but if you have to, you can silence mypy by slicing with a callable, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1.1, 2.2]}, index=[3.3, 4.4])[
    lambda x: (2.5 <= x.index) & (x.index < 3.5)
]

print(df)
# Ouput
     col1
3.3   1.1
```

And so mypy reports `no issues found` on this code.